Set-AzStorageFileContent saves strange line breaks
I have a json file, C:\temp\A.json:
[
    {
        "key": "value"
    }
]

I save this file to an Azure file share using this command:
Set-AzStorageFileContent -Context $SA.Context -ShareName $ShareName -Source C:\Temp\A.json -Path 'A.json' 
This is what the file looks like in the storage account:
"[\r\n    {\r\n        \"key\": \"value\"\r\n    }\r\n]"

Why is this happening? What can I do to have the same line breaks as in the original file?

What are you using to view the file after it has been created? Have you actually tried opening it with a text editor?

I have just re-run your command, I download the uploaded file, and it is showing formatted as the source file.

Downloading and opening with for example VS Code looks ok. It is when viewing / editing the file in the portal it looks different.
Making small adjustments like we do regularly is more convenient in the portal.


Set-AzStorageFileContent saves strange line breaks

Initially, I tried with same command and got the same output in my environment.
Portal:

The above scenario which file is being uploaded with Windows-style line endings. This is why the uploaded file shows \r\n characters.
In the PowerShell command, there is no -Content-type parameter to accomplish this.
So alternatively, I would suggest you use Azure CLI command to upload as json file by adding --content-type application/json in the command.
Command and Output:
PS C:\Users\v-vsettu> az storage file upload --account-key "xxxxxPSCqF2MmpB+AStyKyulA==" --account-name "venkat32612" --path "A.json" --share-name "share1" --source "C:\Users\xx-xx\vxx\oxx\file.json" --content-type application/json
Finished[#############################################################]  100.0000%
{
  "content_md5": "0xexxxxxx0x5c0x270x65",
  "date": "2024-06-18T06:29:17+00:00",
  "etag": "\"0xxxE3C0C\"",
  "file_last_write_time": "2024-06-18T06:29:17.4349836Z",
  "last_modified": "2024-06-18T06:29:17+00:00",
  "request_id": "d07dfabxxxx2a3d000000",
  "request_server_encrypted": true,
  "version": "2022-11-02"
}


Portal:

Reference:
az storage file | Microsoft Learn
